# how to get date between two dates in mysql?

Tags: mysql

In MySql database have `AM_TIMETABLE` table in that

```
UserId        DateTime
 101        2012-08-08 04:00:00 
 102        2012-08-15 10:00:00
 103        2012-08-18 09:00:00
 104        2012-08-24 05:00:00
```

My Question is, i'm passing start-date and end-date then i'll get `DateTime` column date
for ex:

```
select * from AM_TIMETABLE where DateTime<='2012-08-08 00:00:00' and DateTime>='2012-08-20 00:00:00'
```

then i will get 101,102,103 UserId's value.
but i'm getting error `please help`

Comment: The exact error message is always very helpful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work better:

```
select * from AM_TIMETABLE where `DateTime`<='2012-08-20 00:00:00' and `DateTime`>='2012-08-08 00:00:00'
```

`DateTime` might also be a reserved word, not so sure about that. If that's the case, you need backticks around them (a single ` before and after)

Comment: thank you....if i do this one not getting any error but it shows  Empty Set.. result

Comment: That would be because you inversed the two dates, see update ;)

Answer (score 4):

`BETWEEN` is much better for this. and you must also escape `DateTime` since it is a reserve word.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   AM_TIMETABLE 
WHERE  `DateTime` BETWEEN '2012-08-08 00:00:00' AND '2012-08-20 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Datetime field must be inside quotes:

```
SELECT * 
FROM AM_TIMETABLE 
WHERE `DateTime` <= '2012-08-08 00:00:00' AND 
      `DateTime` >= '2012-08-20 00:00:00';
```

or alternatively you can try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM AM_TIMETABLE 
WHERE `DateTime` NOT BETWEEN '2012-08-08 00:00:00' AND '2012-08-20 00:00:00';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the datetime values.

Comment: Also, you might use BETWEEN for readability. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the date in quotes

```
   set @start_date='2012-08-08 00:00:00';
   set @end_date='2012-08-20 00:00:00';
   select * from AM_TIMETABLE where DateTime<=@start_date and DateTime>=@end_date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cast like this with between keyword. I think this is a best approach

```
SELECT * FROM AS_TIMETABLE WHERE DateTime BETWEEN CAST('2012-08-08 00:00:00' AS DATETIME) AND CAST('2012-08-08 00:00:00' AS DATETIME);
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, please consider adding an explanation, so that your answer is more helpful to readers in the future.