# Is this MySQL query valid?

Tags: mysql

So I came across this when I visited a friend. He is trying to show in a table data from his created DB.

This is the part where he asks for the Start and End dates:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="date" name="Date1" value="<?php echo $_POST['StartD'] ?>" style="position:absolute; top:2em; left:7em;">
    <p style="font-family:Calibri; color:green; font-size:15px; position: absolute; top: 1em; left: 18em;">to</p>
    <input type="date" name="Date2" value="<?php echo $_POST['EndD'] ?>" style="position:absolute; top:2em; left:23em;"><br />
    <input type="submit" id="Sbtn" style="cursor: pointer;" name="search_projects" value="Search">
</form>
```

This is now his MySQL query:

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM statisticData WHERE accessDate LIKE '%" . $_POST['StartD'] . "%' OR accessDate LIKE '%" . $_POST['EndD'] . "%' ORDER BY accessDate ASC";
```

Whenever he chooses the Star date: `09-13-13` and an End date: `09-13-13`, the dates such as `09-12-13` also appears in the table. I told him to go and ask the professionals and he says he's too shy. So I'm asking instead.

Here's his code:

```
<div class="scrollableTable">
<center><table class="font1" border="3px solid white" width="70%">
    <thead> 
    <tr id="tblRow">
        <th id="tblData" width="20%">Access Date</td>
        <th id="tblData" width="15%">ID number</td>
            <th id="tblData" width="35%">Name</td>
        <th id="tblData" width="20%">Keyword</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
   <?php
  if ($_POST['search_projects']){

  $con= mysql_connect("...","...","...") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error()); 
   mysql_select_db("...");
   $sql= "SELECT * FROM statisticData WHERE accessDate LIKE '%" . $_POST['StartD'] . "%' AND  accessDate LIKE '%" . $_POST['EndD'] . "%' ORDER BY accessDate DESC";
   $result= mysql_query($sql); 

    while($row= mysql_fetch_object($result))
    { 
    $Date=$row->accessDate; 
    $ID=$row->IDnum;
    $Name=$row->Sname; 
            $Key=$row->keyWord;

    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $Date.  " </td>" . " <td>" . $ID.  " </td>" . " <td>" . $Name.  " </td>". " <td>" . $Key.  " </td>"; 
    echo "</tr>"; 

    }
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</center>";
    }
 ?>
 </div>
```

He wants to allow the user to browse the contents of the database using these date inputs.

[image: start and end date input]

The problem is even when I choose the start and end dates, all the contents are shown in the table. His query does not filter the results at all. I told him to sleep it off, but he just keeps bugging me. So what do you think should he do to finally get some sleep?

Comment: [how to get date between two dates in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11827201/342740) and [Check if the current date is between two dates?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13563494/342740) and [MySQL: query between two dates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822648/mysql-query-between-two-dates)

Comment: Please look into SQL Injection. Your query is wide open.

Comment: Don't concatenate strings into your SQL, use parametized queries instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Just tell your friend that, none is born pro, I read questions more than I answer, also ask if i can't figure it out and that's why i'm learning everyday and getting better than good every day, so your friend is harming to himself, `IMO` and yes I'm not that mush of an expert according to my reps, learning never ends. What i've learned from `1995-2008`, StackOverflow taught me more than that in last two  years, so learn how to learn.

Comment: @SheikhHeera nicely said, SO/SE is a powerful tool if used right.

Comment: @Prix, A perfect place to learn, experts from all over the world.

Comment: I'll be sure to tell him about everyone's suggested revisions and also about what you said @SheikhHeera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People problem is in names:

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM statisticData WHERE accessDate LIKE '%" . $_POST['Date1'] . "%' OR accessDate LIKE '%" . $_POST['Date2'] . "%' ORDER BY accessDate ASC";
```

also:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="date" name="Date1" value="<?php echo $_POST['Date1'] ?>" style="position:absolute; top:2em; left:7em;">
<p style="font-family:Calibri; color:green; font-size:15px; position: absolute; top: 1em; left: 18em;">to</p>
<input type="date" name="Date2" value="<?php echo $_POST['Date2'] ?>" style="position:absolute; top:2em; left:23em;"><br />
<input type="submit" id="Sbtn" style="cursor: pointer;" name="search_projects" value="Search">
</form>
```

**Update:**

- We have to convert time for MySQL
- And use BETWEEN statement

```
<?php
    if ($_POST['search_projects']){

    $startDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['Date1']));
    $endDate   = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['Date2']));

    $con= mysql_connect("...","...","...") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("...");
    $sql= "SELECT * FROM statisticData WHERE accessDate BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate' ORDER BY accessDate DESC";
    $result= mysql_query($sql); 
    ...
```

Comment: Just called my friend and told him to try your suggestions and corrections. He said nothing appears after changing the query and the ones in <form>. I told him there may be something wrong with his table. Could it be the table? @GeorgePHP

Comment: I think problem is in query and maybe also in table, anyway rest is ok from this view. Just can you also post table structure? and the real goal your friend's trying to achieve

Comment: Hello again, I just added the information you asked for. Thank you for the help @GeorgePHP. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Wow, that was fast. I'll call Mat NOW. He was online just a minute ago. Probably fell asleep in front of the computer again.

Comment: Haha you guys seem too funny and wonderful feeling of humor, cheers ;) Let me wake you up anytime

Comment: He's not answering, probably snoring away. I'll be sure to show this to him. Thank you for that quick response @GeorgePHP.

Comment: OK. no prob. Anyway if it does not fix the problem. Mail me to george.garcha at gmail. With files and, if you can export table from MySQL would hasten time needed...

Comment: It's me Mat, d sleepless dude. So any-who, d table is now working properly. Thanks much @GeorgePHP. When I tried it out, I accidentally punched LJ's arm due to d joy of finally seeing d results I've been trying to get. She's a girl so deffo not good. I seriously need to have my own SO account so I won't be ask'n her to ask the pros. for me. Thanks 'gain.

Comment: Ouch, that's too much English for me, for today. But anyway I'm glad to help you. Call me anytime...

Answer (score 0):

Use [BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between).

```
$sql= "
    SELECT * 
    FROM statisticData 
    WHERE accessDate BETWEEN '{$_POST['StartD']}' AND '{$_POST['EndD']}
    ORDER BY accessDate ASC
";
```

And please read [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: 'sup @Glavić, it's the dude with the wrong query and all. I changed my query with yours and I get this error. Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/.../public_html/SysUsers.php on line 60
What d'you think the prob is here? Thanks dude...

Comment: @jr.greenDefender: then you probably have sql error. Run mysql_query like `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); `

Answer (score 0):

it looks good
Try to use this one

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM statisticData WHERE accessDate LIKE '" . $_POST['StartD'] . "' OR accessDate LIKE '" . $_POST['EndD'] . "' ORDER BY accessDate ASC";
```

OR use

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM statisticData WHERE accessDate BETWEEN '" . $_POST['StartD'] . "' AND '" . $_POST['EndD'] . "' ORDER BY accessDate ASC";
```

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: removed %% from both sides of date Or you can also use 2nd method too

Answer (score 0):

used this

```
$sql= "SELECT *
FROM `statisticData`
WHERE (accessDate BETWEEN '".$_POST['StartD']."' AND '" . $_POST['EndD'] . "') ORDER BY accessDate ASC";
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is a bad practice for three reasons:

1) You have an SQL-injection vulnerability here - you must escape your input

2) If you use datetime format in your DB, but want to select by date without time - you should convert type with functions like `DATE()`

3) Using `LIKE` statement is much more slower than exact comparison, which is for your needs is `BETWEEN` statement. And `LIKE` is mostly for just string-like data types

Answer (score 0):

is the  data type of `accessDate` column a datetime, or is it a string? if it is datetime then try the following:

```
'SELECT * FROM `statisticData`
 WHERE  (accessDate BETWEEN ' . $_POST['StartD'] . ' AND ' . $_POST['EndD']) .
'ORDER BY accessDate ASC'
```

it should work, i'm now sql guru