# Timestamps in MySql and Daylight Saving Time [dst]

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which holds different type of data. One of it are birthday dates:

```
ID | meta_key | meta_value
==========================
 1 | birthday | 2011-30-01
 2 | birthday | 2011-30-07
 3 | other    | not_related
```

With a known timestamp I would like to get all birthdays like

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE meta_value = 'birthday' 
     AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(meta_value,'%Y-%m-%d')) = 1296342000
```

which should return the first row (`#1`) but doesn't . The reason is the timestamp has to be `1296345600`

I did a [**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c990/1) to double check that.

It seems the [DST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) is causing the issue but why? Are those UNIX time based timestamps not all UTC? I'll get my timestamp with PHP's [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php) like

```
strtotime('2011-30-01')
```

Edit:

I can't compare strings directly cause I also like to get results from a certain "range" like "All birthdays from August to October"

Comment: why are you using a unix timestamp in the first place? why not just compare to a string date?

Comment: Not possible cause I like to use >=, >, <, <= as well

Comment: `I can't compare strings directly cause I also like to get results from a certain "range" like "All birthdays from August to October"` you can do that with comparing dates... instead of unix timestamp

Comment: here look at this here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c990/3

Comment: Nice :) Is this an "official" method so I can rely on it?

Comment: yes.. it is mysql's date functions in the docs... you can use BETWEEN as well i'll edit my answer

Comment: theres a few links you can look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11827178/how-to-get-date-between-two-dates-in-mysql --- or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822648/how-do-i-query-between-two-dates-using-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure why you need to convert it to a unix timestamp.. first thing the unix timestamp converts to a UTC time [SEE DOCS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

but it seems like you are trying to complicate things more than you should... you can just do a straight date comparison in mysql like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM meta
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(meta_value,'%Y-%m-%d') >= '2011-04-01';
```

you can also do multiple comparison

```
SELECT * 
FROM meta
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(meta_value,'%Y-%m-%d') >= '2011-08-01'
  AND STR_TO_DATE(meta_value,'%Y-%m-%d') <= '2011-10-31';
```

Or you can use BETWEEN

```
SELECT * 
FROM meta
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(meta_value,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2011-08-01' AND '2011-10-31';
```

just as a recommendation.. I would suggest you update the table and change the meta_value to an actual date instead of long text... its a good rule of thumb to store dates as their intended datatype.. :)

Comment: Actually, I'm not convinced that the str_to_date function is actually required here.  With a yyyy-mm-dd date format, I can't think of any values that would give you the wrong answer if you just used the string value of meta_value.

Comment: @DanBracuk that would be true... but I would prefer to let MySQL compare it as a date that way i'm sure. with other date formats it could easily cause problems but might not with this one

Comment: While it's purer to convert to a date first, it's faster to not do so.

Comment: @DanBracuk true.. it wouldn't be a lot faster as mysql handles dates pretty well.. unless there was an index on the longtext column. regardless the OP can see from the comments and adjust accordingly if preffered :)

Comment: The date format is always YYYY-MM-DD but the field type has to be longtext. I know it would be much easier with a date field but this is not possible